# asp.net Textbox cleared after button press

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have 2 textboxes with 2 submit buttons (one for each textbox).  The issue is, when I click on the first submit button, all the other textboxes get cleared.  Is there a way to prevent that?  here is the layout.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button6" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Comment: Have you written event handlers for each button?

Comment: I don't know which one I would look at for this issue.  I have the causes validation set to false

Comment: is the ViewState disabled for the page in the page declarations? I don't see your OnClick properties for the buttons either, do you have any code for those events?

Comment: The ViewStateMode is Inherit.. "<asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" 
    Height="20px" Text="Submit" Width="71px" onclick="Button4_Click" 
            CausesValidation="False" />"

Comment: @vadim Could you post the code inside your Page_Load and inside the button click events? The page declaration would help too. If you have any other events related to page loading, post those as well. Oh and you said ViewStateMode is Inherit... what is the parent's ViewStateMode? Is EnableViewState set to true?

Comment: @vane, ViewState is not relevant here. a TextBox is using the control state. Probably the problem is that the code behind is doing this without checking if it is a postback

Comment: @AmiramKorach You are correct, which is why I was also asking for code from Page_Load, the button click events and any other page events he has defined. The ViewState was just a shot in the dark since there wasn't much to look at in the question as far as sample code.